# Dereference hash list in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm having problem with deferencing hash table. Here is Dumper result of my variable:

```
$VAR1 = \{
    'key' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3',
};
```

I've tried to access elements like this:

```
echo $table->{'key'};
```

But it keeps returning me error:

```
Not a HASH reference at somescript.pl line 10.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{ ... }` returns already a reference to an hash, so `\{ ... }` returns a reference to a reference to an hash (double pointer).

Said so you could then deference it using `${$table}->{'key'}`.

Comment: A better solution would probably not to have a ref to a ref to a hash in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Double referencing can be done by $$variable_name. For more info try this - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html